# How to display a our popup before other installed application startup?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, mobile

Currently, I am working on one security application. In this application, user can select applications for which he/she want to have additional security.

So, before this selected application start, one 'popup/screen with question' will be displayed. and if user answers it right, popup will be dismissed.

So my question is, is it possible to display our popup/screen before other installed application startup?

And if yes, then how to do it?

I searched on google, but didn't find any useful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the relationship to the other application?  Is it one that you made?

Comment: No, Its like, user doesn't want some applications to be opened by others. It can be any application installed on device.

Comment: Then you are out of luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in iOS, Application run in its own sandbox environment. You cannot control other application's  startup and hence this is not feasible using any apple documented APIs.

Comment: Not so fast!  You are likely right, *but* there is a small chance.  If OP created all of the apps (i.e. has control over their startups) then he could feasibly share keychain data among them (i.e. a variable to control this behavior)

Comment: i believe he want to control other installed application which may or may not be developed by OP.

Comment: Probably, but that is the reason for my comment under the original question ;).

Comment: So, it is not possible in iOS to control other application.
:-(

Answer (score 1):

this is not possible.In iOS, Application run in its own sandbox environment so you cannot get any application information. this is only done in jailbreak programming. In witch you hook app startup method method and show your popup first.